# Python program crashes when opening from installer, but not if script is run from Spyder IDE

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt, crash

something weird is going on. I have created a program with PyQt that when opened in Spyder works flawlessly. However if I create the installer with Pyinstall and run it, the program opens normally but once I click on a cell of a table from the main window, it crashes (so I think it has to do with the mousePressEvent() method?

Is there a way where I can debug it, or know where the error is exactly? Because when it crashes the only thing I get is a message of 'Python has stopped working'.

I do have some try blocks around the code and as I said, when opened from the IDE the whole program works as expected.

Please let me know if you need more info

Thanks

EDIT: For a bit more context, if I put the whole mousePressEvent() method in a try block it will still crash when I click the on a cell of the table

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Have you include your external resource (like a image) in PyInstaller with the right path folder ? like in this link and have adapt your code ? https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files ?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't really use external resources, only 1 text file to fetch some data but the path is totally different from the script and dist folder and is already set up in the code. Also this resource is used when initiating the program, which seems to be doing just fine. Thanks Maladra.